# Product Bundles & referenced products in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

What is the preferred way of retrieving referenced products when using hook_commerce_checkout_complete on a line item that is of type Product Bundle.

As an example, the customer has added Product ID 5 (which is a bundle consisting of Products 3 & 4).

How can find it's referenced products at the point of checkout completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this, you can use the following function:

```
function commerce_product_bundle_get_sub_line_items(&$parent_line_item, $reset = FALSE){
    //...
}
```